# get nth number of div in loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi i wanted to know how would i get nth of each div

I added comments in the code on what i want to do

Thanks

```
    <div class = "card">div1</div>
    <div class = "card">div2</div>
    <div class = "card">div3</div>
    <div class = "card">div4</div>
    <div class = "card">div5</div>
    <div class = "card">div6</div>
    <div class = "card">div7</div>
    <div class = "card">div8</div>
    <div class = "card">div9</div>
    <div class = "card">div10</div>
    <div class = "card">div11</div>
    <div class = "card">div12</div>
    so on .........

    $(".card").each(function (i, card) {

      if(div1, div4, div7, div10, ...)
      //do stuff
      else (div2, div5, div8, div11,  ...)
      //do stuff
      else (div3, div6, div9, div12, ...)

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `:nth-child()` pseudo selector.

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

div:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background-color: red;
}

div:nth-child(3n+2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

div:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">div1</div>
<div class="card">div2</div>
<div class="card">div3</div>
<div class="card">div4</div>
<div class="card">div5</div>
<div class="card">div6</div>
<div class="card">div7</div>
<div class="card">div8</div>
<div class="card">div9</div>
<div class="card">div10</div>
<div class="card">div11</div>
<div class="card">div12</div>
```

Comment: also a terrific option :D

Comment: @Mulan for patterns like these, it's the best option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use modulo on the index `i`, such as `i % n` where `n` is the different number of cases you want to check for. For example, if we wanted to break into four (4) conditions -

```js
$(".card").each(function (i, card) {
  if (i % 4 == 0)
    // ...
  else if (i % 4 == 1)
    // ...
  else if (i % 4 == 2)
    // ...
  else if (i % 4 == 3)
    // ...
})
```

```js
for (let i=0; i<20; i++)
  console.log(i, i%4)
```

| i | i % 4 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 0 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 11 | 3 |
| 12 | 0 |
| 13 | 1 |
| 14 | 2 |
| 15 | 3 |
| 16 | 0 |
| 17 | 1 |
| 18 | 2 |
| 19 | 3 |